# Disable progress indication in git command line

Tags: git, user-interface, command-line

I'm using git from within Acme time to time, and carriage returns are not interpreted.  When pushing/pulling code, because git does many *animations* with carriage returns, the output becomes a mess.  Is there any way to disable these progress meters in git?

Comment: Shouldn't do that if the output isn't a tty...  `git fetch | cat` ?

Comment: Or, just use `-q` to defeat the default `--progress`.

Comment: @torek I'm aware of it, but doesn't it suspend all the output?  I still want to see the output from git, but sans the carriage return fancy.

Comment: Yes, it turns everything off.  Using `git fetch | cat` does not seem to help; I still get the progress counts.

Comment: because git prints the progress to stderr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

redirect `stderr` to `cat`. Unlike `-q` it doesn't suppress all output:

```
 /test/media/ffmpeg
$ git fetch 2>&1 | cat
From git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
   cc0e2ba..0bc3de1  master     -> origin/master
   58e212c..41216eb  release/0.10 -> origin/release/0.10
   929100a..69f724a  release/0.11 -> origin/release/0.11
   243396f..101e1b3  release/0.6 -> origin/release/0.6
   1049328..cce6bdc  release/0.7 -> origin/release/0.7
   115efde..8925c44  release/0.8 -> origin/release/0.8
   b6f5a54..320df1c  release/0.9 -> origin/release/0.9
   e28d960..a4c804d  release/1.0 -> origin/release/1.0
   b8eaf47..08dde75  release/1.1 -> origin/release/1.1
   86d4d4b..89c917f  release/1.2 -> origin/release/1.2
   7e73760..b4552cc  release/2.0 -> origin/release/2.0
   69a283e..ac38860  release/2.1 -> origin/release/2.1
 * [new tag]         n0.10.11   -> n0.10.11
 * [new tag]         n2.0.3     -> n2.0.3
From git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
 * [new tag]         n1.1.8     -> n1.1.8
 * [new tag]         n1.2.5     -> n1.2.5
 * [new tag]         n2.1.2     -> n2.1.2
 * [new tag]         n2.1.3     -> n2.1.3
```

Comment: What if I want to see errors but not progress? From example when running git from a script & get a nice log…

Comment: @HuguesM. `git fetch 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cat`

Comment: Thanks & sorry I think I had misunderstood your original answer, it does the job nicely when I don't need to distinguish stderr & stdout. So now those 3 comments are just noise, my bad (moderators please feel free to remove).